# How to insert data from a single form to multiple tables in codeigniter framework ? - below method is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Anyone know how to insert data from a single form to multi tables in codeigniter
i tried below method but it is not working

Model

```
function add_models(){

       $data1 = array(   
      'companykeyid'    => $this->input->post('ckeyid'),
      'name'            => $this->input->post('name'),
      'age'             => $this->input->post('age'),

 );
      $data2 = array(
      'companykeyid'    => $this->input->post('ckeyid'),
      'phrase'          => $this->input->post('phrase'),
      'medialength'     => $this->input->post('medialength'),
 ); 
       $data3 = array(
      'companykeyid'    => $this->input->post('ckeyid'),
      'phrase'          => $this->input->post('phrase')
      'medialength'     => $this->input->post('medialength'),
 ); 
    $this->db->insert('girls', $data1);
    $this->db->insert('movies',$data2);
    $this->db->insert('keywords',$data3);
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with CodeIgnitor, nevertheless how does `triggers` sound?

Comment: Not sure did you made typos, but - you you are missing comma in data3 array, and also - you don't need commas after last element of array...

Answer (score 3):

Method you made is, actually working, i think that your problem is syntax error you have (missing comma in data3 array).

So, this should work:

```
    function add_models(){

       $data1 = array(   
      'companykeyid'    => $this->input->post('ckeyid'),
      'name'            => $this->input->post('name'),
      'age'             => $this->input->post('age')

 );
      $data2 = array(
      'companykeyid'    => $this->input->post('ckeyid'),
      'phrase'          => $this->input->post('phrase'),
      'medialength'     => $this->input->post('medialength')
 ); 
       $data3 = array(
      'companykeyid'    => $this->input->post('ckeyid'),
      'phrase'          => $this->input->post('phrase'),
      'medialength'     => $this->input->post('medialength')
 ); 
    $this->db->insert('girls', $data1);
    $this->db->insert('movies',$data2);
    $this->db->insert('keywords',$data3);
}
```

Important - you have to be sure that field names in tables are right... If this doesn't work, your problem is somewhere else in code (check your controller, view...)

Comment: +1 Nice catch, never post an answer as a comment, and vise-versa  :)

Answer (score 1):

In the array, you call the last value don't have "," get read of it and your model working correctly.

```
$data1 = array(   
  'companykeyid'    => $this->input->post('ckeyid'),
  'name'            => $this->input->post('name'),
  'age'             => $this->input->post('age') <-----
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In sinisake's answer shouldn't:

```
function add_models()
```

be chaged to:

```
function add_models($data)
```

Seems like there will be data to pass from the controller.